# Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined when initialising PDF.JS

Tags: jquery, pdf.js

I am trying to install PDF.JS in a CMS of sorts where the outer skeleton of the page is built for me, including the reference to jQuery (which is still version 1.10.2).

I have tried adding these two lines:

```
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js"></script>
```

And the running this command:

```
<script>
    PDFJS.getDocument('/loc/testpdf.pdf');
</script>
```

But they return this error:

```
VM485:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: PDFJS is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.js?v=910.1:4), <anonymous>:14:1)
at eval (<anonymous>)
at jquery.js?v=910.1:4
at Function.globalEval (jquery.js?v=910.1:4)
at init.domManip (jquery.js?v=910.1:5)
at init.append (jquery.js?v=910.1:5)
at init.<anonymous> (jquery.js?v=910.1:5)
at Function.access (jquery.js?v=910.1:4)
at init.html (jquery.js?v=910.1:5)
```

I have been going round for a couple of hours trying to figure out what's wrong. Have I initialised it correctly or do we think it's related to the outdated version of jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: Is it being loaded after your script is being executed?

Comment: No, it's directly after it.

Comment: If you run `PDFJS` in the console after your page is loaded, is it defined?

Comment: Yes, weirdly it is! I don't understand how...

Comment: Humor me, wrap your code in a timeout for 5 seconds or so - see if it works. You can also try setting `async=false` on your script tags

Comment: That works! So do I need to set a delay every time it runs?

Comment: Oh, definitely not, I was just seeing if that would work. Put your `script` at the bottom of the page and see if that makes a difference. Keep the script reference to JSPDF at the top, and your code at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

try run the script after page loaded;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    PDFJS.getDocument('/loc/testpdf.pdf');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is given because of change of version. The latest version does not support the previous versions functions.  This why it is giving you the error `PDFJS is not define`